# ggvis plot disappears with tooltip and checkBoxInput Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I have a problem with using tooltip in ggvis in my Shiny app. I would like to  use additional info about dot point in ggvis, that's why I create function which need `id` variable:

```
add_info <- function(x) {
  if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
  if (is.null(x$id)) return(NULL)
  df2<- isolate(data)
  df <- df2[df2$id == x$id, ]
  paste0(df$info,
         df$number)
}
```

The problem starts when I work with checkBox buttons in Shiny app i.e. when I unclick all buttons, error comes up:

```
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  wrong result size (2), expected 0 or 1
```

I know that is because of my filter condition which excluded all data. But in that case, I want to see an empty plot when I unclick all checkBox options ( like as in Line plot below). How to do it?

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel(""),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      wellPanel(checkboxGroupInput("variable",label = "",
                         choices = list("a","b","c","d"),
                         selected = c("a"))),
      br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),

      wellPanel(checkboxGroupInput("variable2",label = "",
                         choices = list("a","b","c","d"),
                         selected = c("a")))      
    ),

    mainPanel(
      ggvisOutput("scatter_plot"),
      ggvisOutput("line_plot")
    )
  )
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  dataset <- reactive({
    df <- df1 %>%
      filter(name %in% input$variable)
    df
  })

    data <- reactive({
      dataset() %>%
        mutate(id = 1:n())
    })

  vis2 <- reactive({
    add_info <- function(x) {
      if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
      if (is.null(x$id)) return(NULL)
      df2 <- isolate(data())
      df <- df2[df2$id == x$id, ]
      paste0(df$info,"<br>",
             df$number)
    }
    data() %>%
      ggvis(~number2, ~number, fill = ~name) %>%
      layer_points(size := 100,
                   size.hover := 240,
                   key := ~id) %>%
      add_tooltip(add_info,"hover")
  })
  vis2 %>% bind_shiny("scatter_plot")

  # LinePlot  
dataset_line <- reactive({
  df_line <- df1 %>%
    filter(name %in% input$variable2)
})

    vis <- reactive({

      dataset_line() %>%
        ggvis(~number2, ~number, stroke = ~name) %>%
        layer_lines()

    })
    vis %>% bind_shiny("line_plot")

})
```

**global.R**

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = rep(letters[1:4],each = 5), number = df1_number, number2 = df1_number2,
                  info = "info")

df1_number <-sample(seq(1,20,0.01),20,replace = T)
df1_number2 <-sample(seq(1,5,0.01),20,replace = T)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is actually coming from your `dplyr` `mutate` call.  That error is returned when you try to count with `n()` when there are no rows (i.e. an empty dataset).  This prevents it from creating the `id` variable and causes your downstream problems with `ggvis`.  To fix this, all you need to do is change `1:n()` to `row_number()` (thanks to @docendodiscimus for the suggestion).  To consolidate, remove the `dataset` statement and just use the following:

```
data <- reactive({
          df1 %>%
            filter(name %in% input$variable) %>%
            mutate(id = row_number())
      })
```

that should fix your problem.

Here is a working gist as an example.

```
runGist("https://gist.github.com/cdeterman/806f51c254c523f88f01")
```

Comment: @docendodiscimus, +1, that simplifies it even further!

Comment: @docendodiscimus,cdeterman Hi once again. I try to use it your code right now, but then when I unclick all opitions I get an error: `Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : upper value must be greater than lower value` . I could not remember but probably I reinstall `dplyr` package.

Comment: @Nicolabo, I updated the gist so it loads the packages properly.  It was previously assuming you already had `dplyr` loaded.  It now runs without error on my machine.

Comment: nope, I still has this error `Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : upper value must be greater than lower value.` Before I added `library(dplyr) `on my own. I do not understand because 2 weeks ago everything works. Could you look at my sessionInfo()? gist.github.com/Nicolabo/7e07f5ce2070bc2d1fb4 –

Comment: @Nicolabo, does it work at all for you?  Does the app show the plots when you choose values?

Comment: Shiny works, I can change variables which I want to show in first graph, but when I unclick all buttons I get an error. But if  I can unclick all buttons in second graph I got a empty plot, and it is what I expected. In short, The primary problem which I descirbe at the top still occurs.

Comment: @Nicolabo, looking at your `sessionInfo` again I noticed your `dplyr` is old (0.3).  Try updating and run the app again.

Comment: Very strange. I did `devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")` and right now everything works, but I am sure I did the same thing on Saturday, and there was a problem. Anyway, Thaanks for your patience +1.